# Merging two queries together

Tags: sql, sqlite

This really should be a simple task, but I've been pounding my head on my desk for an hour trying to figure it out.  Maybe someone here can help.  I have two queries.

```
SELECT id FROM confirmed_pairs
```

All this does is return 1-24.  The list of confirmed pairs.  Easy.

This next one, I had to hardcode a "1" into it three times:

```
SELECT 1 AS orig_id, confirmed_pair_id FROM confirmed_pair_team_scores cpts WHERE cpts.confirmed_pair_id != 1 AND team_id <= 56 AND team_id IN
    (SELECT team_id FROM confirmed_pair_team_scores cpts2 WHERE cpts2.confirmed_pair_id = 1)
```

The query works in that it returns two columns with the data that I want.  Though only when orig_id is "1".  I want 1-24, as specified from the first query.

Is there an easy SQL way to do that or should I just do it in PHP and call the query 24 times?  Thanks!

Comment: Sample data would help your question.

Comment: Please edit the question to include the table structure and an explanation of what you're trying to accomplish. "It doesn't work" isn't helpful...

Comment: Thanks for trying.  Someone else on a different site understood the question as written and answered it, no sample data or table structure needed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone on a different site answered the question.  The trick was to use a `CROSS JOIN` like so:

```
SELECT confirmed_pairs.id  AS orig_id, confirmed_pair_id 
    FROM confirmed_pair_team_scores cpts 
    CROSS JOIN confirmed_pairs WHERE
        cpts.confirmed_pair_id != confirmed_pairs.id AND
        team_id <= 56 AND
        team_id IN
            (SELECT team_id FROM confirmed_pair_team_scores cpts2 WHERE   
             cpts2.confirmed_pair_id = confirmed_pairs.id )
```